# The only Energy is Kinetic Energy, isn't it?

Tags: energy

In essence, my thought is that the only energy in the universe is kinetic energy.

People talk about "chemical energy", "potential energy", "thermal energy", "spiritual energy", "cosmic energy", "electrical energy", "magnetic energy", etc. But in terms of actual observable quantities, kinetic energy is the only one whose extensive value can actually can be directly measured quantitatively; like mass, volume, or number. Strictly speaking, it's a combination of two properties (mass and velocity). So maybe it's just a mathematical construct as well.

Thermal energy is just a sum [average] of kinetic energies.

Chemical, electrical, magnetic energies are essentially potential energy.

Spiritual, cosmic, etc. energy can be dismissed as religious in nature, and by definition non-measurable.

Potential energy would possibly be the only exception. However, as mentioned in the comments and elsewhere, potential energy depends on a system and is not an extensive property of a thing.

So my question is, are other forms of energy (or even kinetic energy) real, or are they just a mathematical construct? What is the nature of energy?

Comment: How can you measure kinetic energy?

Comment: Y'know, if you weren't so adamant about looking for a discussion, I think this could be made into a good question for us. (People can help you focus your question in the comments.) But if you really want a discussion, you could try [chat] for starters.

Comment: Single objects don't have potential energy. It's a always a feature of a system. Yeah we talk about gravitational potential energy near the surface of the earth $U = mgh$ as belonging to an objects, but the planet is there in the background and is required for the whole thing to work out. The *system* has potential energy.

Comment: I'm still pondering this. What's the best way to phrase this as a question?

Answer (score 2):

Potential energy can be measured by measuring the mass. E.g. the mass of He-4 is less than the mass of two neutrons and two protons.

Comment: For a simpler example, hydrogen weighs less than a proton plus an electron, but can't someone try to argue that the electromagnetic field has less energy when they are together than when they are apart? After all, the scalar potential is gauge dependent, so how physical can it be?